# Webpack.mix.js file separate module wise but not generating files in public folder

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, npm, package.json

I have a Laravel project with a **large webpack.mix.js file** in the root directory that is nearly 5000 LOC. To organize the file and improve maintainability, I've separated it into individual modules located in their respective directories, such as resources/module1/module1-webpack.js and resources/module2/module2-webpack.js.

Now, **I want to compile and generate files in the public folder only for the module that I am currently working on, instead of compiling the entire webpack file each time.** Ideally, I would like to run a script like **npm run watch:module1** or npm run prod:module1 to achieve this. Additionally, I would like to see the changes made to the module1 file reflected in the browser.

The project is quite large, so npm run watch takes almost 2 minutes to load, and npm run prod takes around 20 minutes to load.

What would be the best approach to achieve this goal? I would appreciate any suggestions or sample scripts that can help me to achieve this.

i used this but it is not generating files on public folder=
**"watch:homepage": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --config=./resources/js/homepage/homepage-webpack.js",**

"prod:homepage": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=./resources/js/homepage/homepage-webpack.js",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find the way.
just create a script in package.json then create condition in webpack.mix.js file like this
package.json --> "watch:xyz" : "cross-env WATCH_TARGET=yourTarget mix
watch"

```
webpack.mix.js -->
if(process.env.WATCH_TARGET == "yourTarget"){
// your webpack files
}
```

your directory/your project>> npm run watch:xy